# Get .app from iPad to Mac

Tags: applications, filesystem

I have made an app and loaded it onto my iPad. I am wondering how I can pull the .app file on my iPad onto my Mac so I can distribute it. I would usually build the app for release to get the .app file outputted, but there is some bug in Xcode that makes the stage 'compiling swift files' last forever. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use the iPad simulator included with Xcode?

Comment: Is this an iOS app or a macOS app?

Comment: I just want the .app file, not to run it. Apologies if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Is the app installed on the iPad built for release or testing? It won't help to pull it off the device if it is built for testing. Might be better to ask a question regarding your Xcode issue.

Comment: Fair point patrix. It is installed as a debug build. However I'm not really fussed as this is just to submit it for a university project to prove I've done it (it won't actually get run). If there's still a way to grab the file I'd love to know.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just run an iOS app on macOS; they're different operating systems. You *can* use the iOS Simulator bundled with Xcode, but even then you can't use the same .app file, because the CPU architecture of the iPad and your Mac are different. If it's your own app, it's easiest just to build & run from Xcode; you can 'install' .app files from another source by copying them to the right folder in Finder. They will of course only run if they specifically built for the Simulator.

Comment: If necessary, I can dig up some details about installing apps in the Simulator, but I'm on mobile right now.